# WordPress url change, only for some categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I have several categories in my WordPress blog. All posts are available through domain.tld/post-title. But now I need different urls for certain topics.

Example:

- Blog > domain.tld/post-title
- Category 1 > domain.tld/category-1/post-title
- Category 2 > domain.tld/category-2/post-title
- Category 3 > domain.tld/post-title

I would prefer not to use a plugin and set everything via custom-template.php or functions.php. I have seen a few solutions with str_replace, but unfortunately none of them worked properly for me.

I also use different layouts for different categories. So I could also use something inside the template file to change the urls.

Answer (score 0):

This should be available through Wordpress' default functionality by using categories for each post & updating the permalinks.

If you already have the categories in place under "Posts -> Categories"

[image: Posting to categories]

and have assigned them to each post then your next step would be setting how it is displayed in your Permalinks tab.

Here you can set site-wide URL structure. In your case it would use

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

[image: Permalinks Page]

which would put the category before the title of the post each time the URL is spun up by Wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this solution seems obvious, but has a big bug.

In my example 4, I show "Category 3 > domain.tld/post-title (but there is a category). In this case your solution doesn't work because there is only always on/off.

I also use different layouts for different categories. So I could also use something inside the template file to change the urls.